# C#: Multiply Decimal with Float?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to perform the following operation:

decimal = decimal? * float / 100

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. What data type do you want the result to be (double, float, int decimal...)?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but just wondering if you chose the data types in the first place. Are you aware of the difference? See this article if not: http://gregs-blog.com/2007/12/10/dot-net-decimal-type-vs-float-type/ It's important to know the difference if you need more reliable accuracy.

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal?", are you actually using a nullable type?

Comment: David is right; this operation is bizarre. Why are you attempting to mix decimal floating point, binary floating point and integer math all in one expression?  It looks like you are taking a percentage of a quantity of money; **why isn't the percentage already in decimal form?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you want the result as a `float`

```
var result = ((float)d) * f / 100;
```

or as a decimal

```
var result = d * ((decimal)f) / 100;
```

I certainly question the mixing of `decimal` and `float` types though. Some context would help!